# Visual Studio minimize undocked windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to minimize undocked windows in Visual Studio 2012. I know that it is possible(maybe it was a extension) but before I reinstalled Visual Studio my undocked windows where independent of the main window. Take alook at this screenshot: [image]

There is now minimize button. Does anyone know where I can change that?

Comment: I [have](http://s11.postimg.org/hh0o6avtv/Untitled.png) a minimize button, so maybe an add-in is involved? (BTW, this is VS2012, i'm just not a fan of the dark theme) ;-)

Comment: I've already disabled all addins. I think I am gonna reinstall it.

Comment: There is no minimize button on undocked windows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Tabs and Windows

Uncheck "Floating tab wells always stay on top of the main window"

Comment: When this man was a child, he was probably very good seeker during games of hide-and-seek.